# Error while scraping: "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, rotten-tomatoes

I am scraping reviews from rotten tomatoes website using the following code:
[Link](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/avatar/reviews?type=user) to the page.

```
import requests
import re
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

r = requests.get("https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/avatar/reviews?type=user")
content = json.loads(re.search('movieReview\s=\s(.*);', r.text).group(1))

movieId = content["movieId"]

def getReviews(endCursor):
    r = requests.get(f"https://www.rottentomatoes.com/napi/movie/{movieId}/reviews/user",
    params = {
        "direction": "next",
        "endCursor": endCursor,
        "startCursor": ""
    })
    return r.json()

data = {"User_Name": [], "Rating": [], "Review": []}
result = {}

for i in range(0, 5):
    #print(f"[{i}] request review")
    result = getReviews(result["pageInfo"]["endCursor"] if i != 0  else "")
    data['User_Name'].extend(t['displayName'] for t in result["reviews"])
    data['Rating'].extend(t['score'] for t in result["reviews"])
    data['Review'].extend(t['review'] for t in result["reviews"])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to convert the above code to a separate function. 
Here I have posted the code where I have tried to get this functionality code but is giving an Error with json.loads(): 
"Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" 
 
I had googled the solution for this and found that adding headers parameter will solve but is not working here.
I am not able to understand what is casing this error. It would be helpful if someone can guide me.

```
import requests
import re
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def getReviews(movieId, endCursor):
    r = requests.get(f"https://www.rottentomatoes.com/napi/{movieId}/reviews/user",
    params = {
        "direction": "next",
        "endCursor": endCursor,
        "startCursor": ""
        },
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    )
    return r.json()

def ScrapeReviews(movie):
    url = "https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/" + movie + "/reviews?type=user"
    req = requests.get(url)
    content = json.loads(re.search('movieReview\s=\s(.*);', req.text).group(1))
    movie_id = content["movieId"]

    data = {"User_Name": [], "Rating": [], "Review": []}
    result = {}

    for i in range(0, 5):
        #print(f"[{i}] request review")
        result = getReviews(movie_id, result["pageInfo"]["endCursor"] if i != 0  else "")
        data['User_Name'].extend(t['displayName'] for t in result["reviews"])
        data['Rating'].extend(t['score'] for t in result["reviews"])
        data['Review'].extend(t['review'] for t in result["reviews"])
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    return df 
d = ScrapeReviews('avatar')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in `getReviews` function, the url should be:

```
"https://www.rottentomatoes.com/napi/**movie**/{movieId}/reviews/user"
```

---

```py
import requests
import re
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def getReviews(movieId, endCursor):
    r = requests.get(
        f"https://www.rottentomatoes.com/napi/movie/{movieId}/reviews/user",
        params={"direction": "next", "endCursor": endCursor, "startCursor": ""},
        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    )
    return r.json()


def ScrapeReviews(movie):
    url = "https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/" + movie + "/reviews?type=user"
    req = requests.get(url)
    content = json.loads(re.search("movieReview\s=\s(.*);", req.text).group(1))
    movie_id = content["movieId"]

    data = {"User_Name": [], "Rating": [], "Review": []}
    result = {}

    for i in range(0, 5):
        result = getReviews(
            movie_id, result["pageInfo"]["endCursor"] if i != 0 else ""
        )
        data["User_Name"].extend(t["displayName"] for t in result["reviews"])
        data["Rating"].extend(t["score"] for t in result["reviews"])
        data["Review"].extend(t["review"] for t in result["reviews"])

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return df


d = ScrapeReviews("avatar")
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
        User_Name  Rating                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         Review
0           Joe D     5.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       To me this is the most perfect blockbuster of all.\nLove Sam Worthington's empty cup, I find his everyman acting compelling, Saldana may be the most beautiful woman on the planet with her trademark perfect posture, and Sigourney adds class with extra to spare wherever she goes.\nThe planet Pandora remains the real star, and the revelation that we're the bad guys and the spiritual tree-huggers were right all along, I find genuinely touching every time.\nFirst class and I can't wait for more of Cameron's magic touch.
1         Jimmy W     1.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           The fact that this movie can make the most money of all time and also gain a following of hive-minded morons to defend it says more about the state of society than it does the movie itself. For a movie that's meant to make a point about abusive use of the environment, they sure seem to indulge in the use of massive amounts of expensive technology that no doubt utilized way more than its fair share of natural resources. Oh well, at least you can pretend to be vindicated by the box office numbers.
2      Goudkuil E     1.5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Apart from the visuals everything feels uninspired and thrown together using a old cliche of an outsider seeing what's wrong with what he's people have been doing falling in love then whiching sides. The acting is ok, the dialogue is kinda rough. The movie is padded with a lot of nice scenique views with no real narrative meaning.
3       Antonio D     4.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  o filme possui uma fotografia muito bela e, mesmo o filme sendo de 2009 não conseguimos encontrar defeitos em relação a montagem e fotografia, a história é satisfatória e é um reflexo do que sabemos que aconteceu no inicio da colonização

...and so on.
```